# different p-values from resampling and traditional methods

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, resampling

I'm not sure if this is hard to answer without the original data, but let's give it a go.

I'm calculating the difference in proportions for two diagnostic methods:

```
      outcome
test     0  1
method1 22 30
method2 18 39
```

Using R and `prop.test(c(30, 39), c(52, 57))` gives me a p = 0.3361.

Using R and the [infer package](https://infer.netlify.com/articles/observed_stat_examples.html) "Two categorical (2 level) variables" gives me p = 0.250.

Is such a big difference to be expected when using permutation, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you doing and why?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You mean how and why I'm using that R package? Or the purpose of the comparison?

Comment: How did you get that table? What are those values and methods? What is the purpose of prop.test and what are you doing with the infer package?

Comment: Alright :) The table is from R `table(mydata)`. The methods are two different biopsy methods for diagnosing cancer, so the outcomes are 0 = no cancer, 1 = cancer. The purpose of prop.test is to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference in detection of cancer with the two methods. I'm testing the same hypothesis using infer with the method described under "Two categorical (2 level) variables" - comparing the observed difference in proportions to the null distribution of 1000 permuted samples.

Comment: If I understand your table correctly you should be comparing the methods, that is `prop.test(c(22,30),c(18,39))`.

Comment: Thats what I think I'm doing with `prop.test(x = c(30, 39), n = (52, 57))`. `prop.test(c(22,30),c(18,39))`throws an error `elements of 'x' must not be greater than those of 'n'`

Comment: Never mind, it's correct. So the question is why the two tests give different p-values? The difference doesn't seem that big, considering that one is simulated. Either case you retain your null hypothesis.

Comment: If these are the same cases assessed by the different methods, don't you need a method for paired samples?

Comment: You need to give us more details about the study design as it looks on the face of it that @Björn is correct here and you are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: They are not the same cases, 52 got method1 and 57 got method2. However, the group of 52 ALSO got method2, and I'm planning to use McNemars test in that group comparison to account for paired/repeated measures.

Answer (score 0):

The difference was due to Yates continuity correction. It's set to default = TRUE in prop.test().

prop.test(c(30, 39), c(52, 57), correct = FALSE) yields a more similar p-value.